# How do I Generate a Windows Form (from a programmatically created project)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

First want to mention that I am NOT asking how to create a Windows form. I have a unique situation where a person decided to create an entire Windows Forms Application programmatically. What I am asking is...

Is there any way to work backwards and generate a designer file, or something we can visually work through, from this?

What we do have is a programmatically created "Designer" file...

Is there a way to do this?

Steve

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What does it mean to "create an entire Windows Forms Application programmatically"?

Comment: I'd begin by having a look here: http://zetcode.com/gui/vbwinforms/ It's for Mono, but the similarities are striking and you should be able to get where you want from there.

Comment: What I mean by, "create an entire Windows Form Application programmatically," means... A previous developer decided to just create all buttons, controls, etc. by typing as opposed to using Visual Studio. Now, we have to support it. It's too much trouble to continue programmatically editing the form as opposed to visually.

Comment: Are you sure about this? If you have a `FormName.Designer.vb` partial class file with readable code, that file was likely created by Visual Studio. That's how the designer works these days, and there is no other designer file for layout.

Comment: A blank VB file was opened up and literally every button was programmatically typed into the file with no strategy in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably no quick way to do this.

There are two normal reason someone would choose to build a form entirely in code, rather than via the designer.

One is when the controls that will be shown on the form will be determined at run time, rather than up front at design time. This could be because they are using the same form for a number of different screens/views by loading/unloading the controls they need for a specific view, or it could be that the form is data driven, where information about the controls you want is stored in a database.

The other reason to build a form entirely in code is when you are using custom controls that don't work with the forms designer.

Any of these reasons will require you to (at minimum) rebuild the form in the designer by hand, and may require you to re-create controls from scratch or even prevent you from using the designer at all.

Comment: In our particular case none of these reasons apply, thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

First off, all forms are created "programatically." Meaning all the designer does is generate code for you, but it's still C#/VB the same as if you write the code yourself. [There's no magic here](http://ericlippert.com/2015/06/04/its-not-magic/).

The VS Designer uses [partial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) classes to separate the generated UI code from your code. The Designer is a bit odd in that it has its own custom parser for the UI code ([which causes odd quirks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22788/Inheriting-a-Form-from-an-Abstract-Class-and-Makin)) but it simply parses the code. And in my experience, it's fairly flexible and isn't very dependent on the strict sturcture and format it generates itself (although it will reformat the code to fit it's own conventions). So if you can put all the "UI building" code in an `InitializeComponent()` method of a class that inherits from `System.WIndows.Forms.Form`, you should be good.

You will probably want to put this a separate file (use partial classes) and call the `InitializeComponent()` method from the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Chad.